# Shorten / Guarantee SLA for DRUID Queries

Tags: druid

I am interested in using Druid to feed data to our frontend for customer reporting needs.  In order to do so, we have strict SLA requirements of having queries return back in 500ms or less.

For most part this is possible by either tailoring the datasource case by case i.e. creating different aggregation level tables.  Is there a way to avoid creating different versions of the same datasource by still achieve reasonable SLAs?  Ideally we want to have one datasource at the lowest level granularity and have that be used for all the UI use cases.  Is there some of stack that people usually use on top of Druid in these situations?